# The act of making questions for exams and assignmets?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

and also what is the person designing questions called ?
I need it to answer a question about my role as a teacher assistant which was designing assignments.

in my language (Persian) it can be called Designing questions and question Designer. I wonder if these words have a meaning in English and can be used or not.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word you are after is ***set***. It means to produce questions for someone (students) to answer.

> To set an examination or a question paper means to decide what questions will be asked in it. [(Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/set)

The act of writing or setting exam questions is ***exam paper setting***.

And ***paper setter*** is someone who sets their exam questions.

You may like to consider ***examiner*** too.

> A person who sets and marks exams to test people's knowledge or proficiency. [(Oxford Living Dictionaries)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/examiner)